# How to make a login page to addon to my current code

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have made a successful registration system that inputs data into the database (phpmyadmin).

Now i am trying to tackle another major problem the login system. I have 2 parts of it done. 
Part 1 = the database to code link 
Part 2 = the form.

What I need is code to pull the data from the data base and authenticate it and either transfer to a home.php page or go back to the login page with an echo "Sorry your Log-in information is incorrect". I have tried this many times and all have failed miserably. Any code you can give me to login would be much appreciated. So the code i have now is just 2 parts not the third and I am hoping some one on here can help me through making this login page.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('XXXXXX', $link);
$host="XXXX"; 
$db_user="XXXXX"; 
$db_password="XXXXXX"; 
$database="XXXXXXX"; 
$link = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);

$link = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);
if (!$link) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use the DB : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "Mysql Connected Successfully";
}


?>


<font color="red">
<h1>Log-In</h1>

<p>Please Enter your details below to Log-in</p>

<form method="post" action="home.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
<fieldset>
<label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username"        id="username" /><br />
<label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"          id="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log-In" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</font>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you cant select the db before you connect to the server

Comment: You need to quit using `mysql_` functions **they are deprecated**.

Comment: So I could move the select db code below the connect code?

Comment: I realize the functions are "deprecated" but that is not the answer or input I need.

Comment: It doesn't matter if that is not the input you need, you will get that input from nearly anyone who answers or looks at a PHP question where those functions are used until **everyone** stops using them @Xxcoder14xX Additionally your OP came in dictating many things about how folks should answer you. In my experience on SO that doesn't work well, often ends up with a heavily DV'd and sometimes closed question. Just some helpful hints for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code for process.php **NOTE: you MUST make sure that you cleanse any input that a user provides so that you protect your server!** This example does not take care of all of the possibilities, it is just to get you started -

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = $user AND `password` = $pass")) {
    if(0 != mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        header('Location: home.html');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Your login has failed.";
    }
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

**Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: If I am using this code I am keeping my form correct?

Comment: Yes - keep your form, but change to `mysqli_` methods.